# Pass user input to authorization header in post request using python

Tags: python, xml, post

I want to send user input (username and password) to the Header in post request. I have this so far-

```
import requests                                                                                                                                                              
import urllib3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
import json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
import getpass                                                                                                                                                               
urllib3.disable_warnings()                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                            
url = "https://127.0.0.1"                                                                                                                               
username = raw_input("Enter the username: ")                                                                                                                                 
password = getpass.getpass()                                                                                                                                                 
payload = "relevance=(members of computer group whose (name = \"ABC\") of computers)"                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                             
headers = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    'username': username,                                                                                                                                                    
    'password': password,                                                                                                                                                    
     'Content-Type': 'application/xml',                                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                                                            
response = requests.post(url, verify=False, headers=headers, payload=payload)                                                                                                  
print(response)
```

I'm getting a 401 error. But when I use Basic auth, it works-

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic akjrgbierhgiehg',
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: maybe it want the credentials in the body ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Username and password go in the `auth` keyword of requests. Remove them from headers but pass them in `requests.post`

```
headers = {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     'Content-Type': 'application/xml',                                                                                                                                      
}
response = requests.post(url, verify=False, headers=headers, payload=payload, auth=(username, password))
```

Comment: I'm getting the below error-
 response = requests.post(url, verify=False, headers=headers, payload=payload, auth=(username, password))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 108, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'payload'

Comment: I renamed "payload" to "data" and that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @jenhenry Yes, sorry the kwarg "payload" should be "data"